# How to load multiple sheet of excel(2016) file in ssis

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

This code perfectly work on my machine (I have excel 2010) but when my supervisor tried to run but not work on his machine(he have excel 2016) so for excel 2016 do i need to change connection 
   ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";??

```
 string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
        string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
        string SchemaName = Dts.Variables["User::SchemaName"].Value.ToString();
        string SheetNameToLoad = Dts.Variables["User::SheetNameLike"].Value.ToString();

        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
        FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

        //Declare and initilize variables
        string fileFullPath = "";


        SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBconnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

        ////Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            fileFullPath = FolderPath + "\\" + file.Name;
            MessageBox.Show(fileFullPath);

            //    //Create Excel Connection
            string ConStr;
            string HDR;
            HDR = "YES";
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);

        //    //Get Sheet Name
            cnn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            string sheetname;
            sheetname = "";
            //Only read data from provided SheetNumber

            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {



                sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(sheetname);

                //Load the Data if Sheet Name contains value of SheetNameLike 
                if (sheetname.Contains(SheetNameToLoad) == true)
                {



                    //Load the DataTable with Sheet Data so we can get the column header
                    OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select  * from [" + sheetname + "] where CityName ='ARLINGTON'", cnn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adp.Fill(dt);
                    cnn.Close();



                    //Load Data from DataTable to SQL Server Table.
                    using (SqlBulkCopy BC = new SqlBulkCopy(myADONETConnection))
                    {
                        BC.DestinationTableName = SchemaName + "." + TableName;

                        BC.WriteToServer(dt);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did he get the error says ACE provider is not registered? If so, your supervisor need to download and install this on his machine:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: yup i already download Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable on his machine still getting same error. Is  ace.oledb.12 still work for excel 2016?@ LONG

Comment: can you paste the full error message? If it says ACE.OLEDB.12.0, then yes, I do not have 2016 installed, but if it says that, you need to download and install the correct version (32bit or 64 bit), then reboot

Comment: getting Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. but when i checked on his machine he didnot have ace.oledb.12.0 then i installed but still getting same error @LONG

Comment: that is the general message, since you have debugged it, it should be the installation issue, did you install the correct one and reboot your machine?

Comment: yup i did,i will reinstall again and i will let you know.@LONG

Comment: just reinstall ace.oledb.12.0 (32 bit version) on his machine that work perfectly thanks @LONG